# What's the difference between an interface and a design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, interface, observer-pattern

I have a hard time knowing when something is an interface or a design pattern. For example what are observer - observerable? And what is MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get your confusion. An Interface is simply a set of methods the class that implements it, 'promises' to implement. A pattern's definition may vary and this is the one I found online:

> Design patterns represent the best practices used by experienced object-oriented software developers. Design patterns are solutions to general problems that software developers faced during software development. These solutions were obtained by trial and error by numerous software developers over quite a substantial period of time.

As per this example you've given, it is my understanding that `Observable` would be an Interface, that every object that wants to have a trait of "observability" should implement. On the other side:

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to implement distributed event handling systems.

The key point here is : **usually by calling one of their methods**. Every object that is in the list of "dependents" needs to implement the `Observable` interface as to be sure that it has the required method that the Observer will call, regardless of what type of object it is. By defining an interface which has the aforementioned method, you can guarantee that different classes will provide their own implementation of the method, which is unimportant at the place where the method is called. All it matters is that the method **exists**.

I hope I was in a way helpful and clear.